# How to create a config file and access in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, ini

Actually i am working selenium by using python ,So i need to create a framework in keyword driven .

How can i create a property file in python , and please give me an example ?

Thanks and Regards, 
Deepak

Answer (score 1):

Use ConfigParser module

## or.properties

```
[Login] 
email = email_id
psw   = abcd1234
```

`config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
 config.read("or.properties")
 config.get("Login", "psw")`

Comment: Nice Job Eknath :P